How to Upload a media item with alt text and description
I'm trying to upload a media file to the media library with the altText and caption for it using the media endpoint: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#create-a-media-item
However, The alt text and the description is not updated in the media file. Please help.
 var userName = userInput['userName'];
    var password = userInput['password'];

    var headers = {
      Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(userName + ':' + password),
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + imageFileName,
      "Content-Type": mimeType,
    };

    var formData = {
      caption: fileAltText,
      description: fileCaption,
      file: blob // Assuming blob contains the image file data
    };

    var options = {
      method: "post",
      headers: headers,
      payload: formData
    };

    var response = invokeFetchURL(siteURL, getMediaEndPoint(), options);
    //var mediaData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    //var mediaPath = mediaData.source_url;

    return response;

The invokeFetchURL method here posts the request to the endpoint. I need help with creating proper header info and the right payload with blob and altText and captions.

Are you using the core media endpoint? Have you checked the docs? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#create-a-media-item
